# Self-encrypting hard drive without support in BIOS for ATA password

Tags: encryption

If my mainboard does not support to set an ATA password, is it possible to create a pre-boot authentication setup with ubuntu (or debian) where I can enter my password(s) and then unlock and boot (to ubuntu or windows) from one of my (SED) hard drives?

Comment: You can do it if you only want Ubuntu if you install with the full disk encryption option.